# Use a struct or create two methods? C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

If anyone can think of a better way please let me know:

I have a windows form that displays different links to three sites: Yahoo Finance, Bloomberg and Merrill Lynch. Yahoo and Bloomberg both use a separate class that utilized `HttpWebRequest` to return the headlines as links, but because ML is so secure, I had to create a separate class that uses `WebBrowser` to stay logged in.

I'm going to use this class to retrieve a list of hyperlinks, but I'm not sure if I should do either of the following:

1. Create two methods: One for the inner text of the links, and the other for the link addresses
2. Design a link struct that can hold both values or
3. Something I haven't thought of.

Comment: Both the first and the second would be all fine. If, for the first, you'll need to iterate the DOM twice, I'd go for the second option. There is some opinion and taste here as well

Comment: I'm leaning towards the second, obviously for code-clarity purposes. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the first and the second would be all fine. If, for the first, you'll need to iterate the DOM twice, I'd go for the second option. There is some opinion and taste here as well.

The third option would be to use the built-in [tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).